# How do you compare two images in python to return a numerical difference and time elapsed?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, imagemagick, image-comparison

1. numerical difference is expected as positive or negative with decimal places
2. compare the visual appearance of each image, not their binary contents

for example:
file1.png & file2.gif
diff 0.23
time elapsed  0.843

I have tried

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops

...

one = Image.open("file1.png")  
two = Image.open("file2.gif")  
diff = ImageChops.difference(one, two)  
print(diff)
```

But `ImageChops` does not work for comparing .gif and .png files. Error is

```
python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageChops.py", line 102, in difference  
    return image1._new(image1.im.chop_difference(image2.im))  
ValueError: images do not match
```

Will `imagemagick` or `numpy` work? has to support .png, .gif (.jpg, .bmp are optional)

Comment: Are you certain the error is due to different file formats? Or could it be that images are of different size or using different color format or one of many other possible issues?

Comment: Try running `print(one.format, one.size, one.mode)` and the same for the second image.

Comment: try cv2.matchTemplate()

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the modes of the images.

```
print(one.mode)
print(two.mode)
```

If those two modes != are not equal to each other, then it can bomb out as you are seeing.